# Python: Compare values from 2 dictionaries with the same key

Tags: python

Hello i am new to python and i have a question about dictionaries:

Let's say we have a dictionary :

```
Cars {"Audi": {"Wheels": 4, "Body": 1, "Other": 20},"Ford": {"Wheels": 2, "Body": 3, "Other":10},"BMW": {"Wheels": 5, "Body": 0.5, "Other": 30}}
```

And and other dictionary:

```
Materials {"Wheels": 30, "Body": 5, "Other": 110}
```

I want to return the number of cars i  can produce with the materials i have so:

```
def production(car,Materials):
return

production("Audi",Materials)
```

My output in this example should return the number 5,because there are only 5 body parts to use.
I was thinking to make it somehow like this:
 Divide the values from Materials with values from cars. Then write the numbers to an other list ,and then return the min number in whole.

More exaples:

```
production("BMW",Materials)
3.0 # because the value of key only is 110 and for 3 cars we need 90 other:
production("Ford",Materials)
1.0 # because the value of key body is 3 and for 1 car we need 3 body:
```

I thank you in advance for everything.

Comment: for any random car, or any specific car or have any priority??

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Perhaps because they are being treated like JSON and should be objects instead of dictionaries!

Comment: Hackaholic: I would need this for any of the cars in the list,other keys are not in question.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The `Materials` dict represents the amount of materials available to build a car. An `"Audi"` requires 4 "Wheels", 1 "Body", and 20 "Other". So, if you start using the materials in the `Materials` dict to build cars based on the `"Audi"` requirements, you'll run out of `"Body"` materials after building 5 Audis. Hence you return 5. (You'd still have 10 "Wheels", and 10 "Other" left over.)

Comment: That is the point yes

Answer (score 5):

If what you want is to see how many of any given car can be created without actually affecting the contents of `Materials`, you could write your method like so:

```
def number_of_units_creatable(car_key):
    required_parts = Cars[car_key]
    return min(Materials["Wheels"] // required_parts["Wheels"], 
               Materials["Body"] // required_parts["Body"], 
               Materials["Other"] // required_parts["Other"])
```

In production, you'd want to add conditional guards to check whether your `Cars` and `Materials` have all the required keys. You'll get an exception if you try to get the value for a key that doesn't exist.

This will allow you to figure out the maximum number of any given car you can create with the resources available in `Materials`.

I'd strongly recommend you not use nested dicts like this, though - this design would be greatly helped by creating, say, a `Materials` class, and storing this as your value rather than another dictionary. abarnert has a little more on this in his post.

Another note, prompted by abarnert - it's an extremely bad idea to rely on all a shared, static set of keys between two separate dictionaries. What happens if you want to build, say, an armored car, and now you need a gun? Either you have to add `Gun: 0` within the required attributes of every car, or you'll run into an exception. Every single car will require an entry for every single part required by *each and every* car in existence, and a good deal of those will signify nothing other than the fact that the car *doesn't* need it. As it stands, your design is both very constraining and brittle - chance are good it'll break as soon as you try and add something new.

Comment: I think you mean `math.floor`

Comment: Also, why use `math.floor` in the first place when Python has a floordiv operator (`//`) built in?

Comment: @abarnert Pure, unadulterated forgetfulness. Thanks.

Comment: I think this may be a bad idea. You're treating the data (the keys to `Materials` and the `Cars` subclasses) as if they were part of your code (static attribute names). It's basically the same problem as creating a bunch of variables like `car1`, `car2`, `car3` instead of a list `cars`, but in reverse. Of course you're right that it's possible that his design is bad and these keys actually _are_ static attributes rather than arbitrary data, but I wouldn't just assume that.

Comment: @abarnert Based on the comment he posted just a second ago, it does seem like that's what he's doing. But you're right, that was a bit of a leap on my part. I'll add another note explaining why it's also a really bad idea to rely on a static set of keys shared between multiple dicts as well.

Comment: @furkle: I think your answer already explains that a class would be a good idea if (as it seems is true) there's a fixed set of attributes. An example might be a nice bonus, but I don't know if it's necessary.

Comment: @abarnert Heck, maybe it'll be helpful to point out that not every single car is created the same way, and that forcing every single car every single item required by any car in existence within its requirements dictionary is a bad idea. Anyway, it's a good suggestion on your part, thanks.

Comment: your code won't actually run, `Materials[car_key]` would give a keyError

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Fixed - was from a typo I apparently only half-fixed earlier. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If the set of possible materials is a static collection—that is, it can only have "Wheels", "Body", and "Other"—then you really ought to be using a class rather than a dict, as [furkle's answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26981544/908494), but you *can* fake it with your existing data structure, as his answer shows.

However, if the set of possible materials is open-ended, then you don't want to refer to them one by one explicitly; you want to loop over them. Something like:

```
for material, count in car.items():
```

In this case:

```
return min(Materials[material] // count for material, count in car.items())
```

Comment: Yes materials is a static collection,only the cars needed to produce can be different

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over materials and decrement the values until one become 0:

```
def production(car, materials):
    count = 0
    while 0 not in materials.values():
        for part in cars[car]:
            materials[part] -= 1
        count += 1
    return count
```

If you don't want to change the material dict:

```
def production(car, materials):
    count = 0
    vals = materials.values()
    while not 0 in vals:
        for ind, part in enumerate(Cars[car]):
            vals[ind] -= 1
        count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: Small point: it doesn't seem from his design like he necessarily wants to affect the values within `Materials`. My interpretation was that he wanted to be able to tell how many he *could* make.

Comment: @furkle, well you could just copy the dict but either materials is being thrown away or the values will need to be updated.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not entirely sure why he has two global dictionaries, but only passes `Materials`. I was assuming confusion on his part, but that might be unfair.

Comment: @furkle, I suppose it is hard to really know from seeing a toy example but I suppose on a larger scale classes are the answer anyway